# Differences in populate a DataGridView using SQLiteDataAdapter vs. SQLiteDataReader

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

For populate a DataGridView with data from a SQLite DataBase I think the easy way is using SQLiteDataAdapter, populate a Table and make the Table the DataSource of the DataGridView, something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cdmDataTable.Click

    Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDataBase.sqlite;Version=3")

    Try
        Using (conn)
            conn.Open()

            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM users"
            Dim cmdDataGrid As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = cmdDataGrid
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            Dim readerDataGrid As SQLiteDataReader = cmdDataGrid.ExecuteReader()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

**Is there any advantage using SQLiteDataReader instead of SQLiteDataAdapter?**

Comment: It is easier to use the adapter but the SQLiteDataAdapter internally uses SQLiteDataReader to fill the table.  Using the reader and filling yourself the grid will result in one less loop. If you don't have perfomance problems stick with the adapter. (Or use a list of your user objects with an ORM)

Comment: @Steve Actually, with a simple SQL SELECT and no where clause, a DA is faster than a DataReader.  It seems odd, and the difference is quite small but it is consistent (~.5 sec for 150k rows).  It is hard to measure on <5k rows, so dont worry about it.

Comment: Indeed, It is a lot of time that I don't use anymore directly a DataAdapter or a DataReader. I really prefer to use a Micro ORM like Dapper. Also I think that perhaps it is best to focus performance optimizations in reducing the number of rows and columns retrieved and proper indexing.

Comment: @Steve thanks a lot. Which ORM do you suggest?

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the info. In my case is a really small database I will continue using DA!

Comment: `a Micro ORM like Dapper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data adapter is a higher level component that connects a DataTable to the underlying database. It can fill the DataTable and it can sync the changes on the DataTable back to the database. The DataAdapter uses a DataReader internally to read the data from the table.

There is no significant advantage using a DataReader over a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable.